# How to reduce space in begining of itemize?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

I am writing one list after one text.

```
 Following is list items:


   1. Pen
   2. Hen
   3. Ten
```

I need to reduce spacing between text (Following is list items:) and beginning of list (Pen). How can I reduce it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the package `enumitem`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0ex]
\item various stuff
\end{enumerate}
```

The package allows you easy access to change the parameters which control the list environments: `enumerate`, `description`, and `itemize`.

Other parameters to adjust vertical spacing are:  `partopsep`, `parsep`, `itemsep`.  You pass these to the environment through an *optional* argument as *keys* as I did above with `topsep=0ex`.

Answer (score 2):

Another Way would be, to use `paralist`

```
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

  \begin{compactitem}
    \item something
    \item something else
  \end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

This would also minimize the space between each item. You can use it as `compactitem` `compactenum` `compactdist` and so on.

Comment: I actually enjoy this solution more than the `enumitem` solution because it allows me to use the `enumerate` package.