# How to reduce space in beginning but not in end of itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

This refers to my question.

[How to reduce space in begining of itemize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94951/how-to-reduce-space-in-begining-of-itemize/94952#94952)

`[topsep=0]` also reduces space between the itemize and text below to itemlist. I just want to reduce space in the beginning, not in the last.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to define your own environment to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{toplessitemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

{\let\par\relax\lipsum[2]}
\begin{toplessitemize}
\item stuff
\item stuff
\item 
\end{toplessitemize}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more control over the spacing you might try something like

```
\newenvironment{toplessitemize}{\vspace{\dimexpr-\topsep+<FACTOR>\baselineskip\relax}%
                                \begin{itemize}}
                               {\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I need one line space in the begining of itemize. How can i control by parameter.