# How to control spacing in end of itemize?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

This refers to my previous question

[How to reduce space in beginning but not in end of itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99033/how-to-reduce-space-in-begining-but-not-in-end-of-itemize/99037#comment216538_99037)

Now I need to control spacing in the last of itemize like I could control in the beginning as suggested in previous question. How can I control it?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of [Vertical space in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/2693)?

Comment: @AlanMunn, I think this is not what i want. I need to control spacing before and after itemlist list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following addresses *both* questions - how to adjust the separation above and below an `itemize` environment. It's done using a key-value approach (thanks to [`keyval`](ht, which allows you to set `beforeskip` and `afterskip` (defaults are `0pt`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval
\makeatletter
\newlength{\mylist@beforeskip}
\newlength{\mylist@afterskip}
\define@key{mylist}{beforeskip}{\setlength{\mylist@beforeskip}{#1}}
\define@key{mylist}{afterskip}{\setlength{\mylist@afterskip}{#1}}
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][,]
  {\setkeys{mylist}{beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=0pt,#1}%
   \par\vspace*{\mylist@beforeskip}%
   \begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}%
   \vspace*{\mylist@afterskip}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text. Regular \verb|itemize|:
\begin{itemize}
  \item stuff \item stuff \item 
\end{itemize}
Here is some text. New \verb|mylist|:
\begin{mylist}
  \item stuff \item stuff \item
\end{mylist}
Here is some text. New \verb|mylist| with \verb|beforeskip=-\baselineskip|:
\begin{mylist}[beforeskip=-\baselineskip]
  \item stuff \item stuff \item
\end{mylist}
Here is some text. New \verb|mylist| with \verb|afterskip=-\baselineskip|:
\begin{mylist}[afterskip=-\baselineskip]
  \item stuff \item stuff \item
\end{mylist}
Here is some text. New \verb|mylist| with \verb|beforeskip=afterskip=-\baselineskip|:
\begin{mylist}[beforeskip=-\baselineskip,afterskip=-\baselineskip]
  \item stuff \item stuff \item
\end{mylist}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed 0 pt to 10pt still no change. I need to control its spacing in points. How can i do it?